# Attempting to deploy Dell Command Update intunewin package using InTune

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, package, intune

I'm having some trouble deploying Dell Command Update software for my users using InTune. I downloaded the most recent version of Dell Command Update(Dell-Command-Update-Application_HYR95_WIN_5.0.0_A00.EXE) and have it stored in a folder "C:\Dell Command Update". In the same folder, I have a PS script that would set "Dell Client Management Service" enabled and running, then install the Dell Command Update software. I also have a "MySettings.xml" file that will also force overwrite the default "MySettings.xml" on all machines. All this is done as Administrator.

In the "C:\Dell Command Update" folder, I have:

- "Dell-Command-Update-Application_HYR95_WIN_5.0.0_A00.EXE" file
- "MySettings.xml" file
- PS Script to run and install the package.

I also have the "DellCommandUpdate.msi" file stored in the same folder, but not used in this process.

Using Microsoft Win32 Content Prep tool to create an intunewin file, I would have the source folder as "C:\Dell Command Update", the setup file as "Dell-Command-Update-Application_HYR95_WIN_5.0.0_A00.EXE", and the output as "C:\Dell Command Update".

The issue I'm having is the package won't install successfully on all machines. It will turn on "Dell Client Management Service" but won't install Dell Command Update.

Here is the script:

```
Push-Location

# Set Variables
$DellCommandPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\CommandUpdate"

# Start Logging
$PackageName = "Dell-Command-Update"
$PathLocal = "$Env:Programfiles\MDM"
Start-Transcript -Path "$PathLocal\Log\$PackageName-install.log" -Force

#Start and run Dell Client Management Service
$ServiceName = "DellClientManagementService"
Set-Service -Name $ServiceName -StartupType Automatic -Status Running   


try {

    # Create Temp folder
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$PathLocal\Temp\$PackageName" -Force

    # Install Latest Dell Command Update
    Start-Process "Dell-Command-Update-Application_HYR95_WIN_5.0.0_A00.exe" -ArgumentList "/s" -Wait
    
    # Import Config - Force Overwrite of Existing Settings XML
    Copy-Item -Path "DellCommandMySettings.xml" -Destination "$PathLocal\Temp\$PackageName" -Force
    Set-Location -Path "$DellCommandPath"
    ./dcu-cli.exe /configure -importSettings="$PathLocal\Temp\$PackageName\DellCommandMySettings.xml"
            
    # Disable Initial Welcome Screen
    if (Test-Path -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Dell\UpdateService\Clients\CommandUpdate\Preferences\CFG") {
        [void](New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Dell\UpdateService\Clients\CommandUpdate\Preferences\CFG" -Name "ShowSetupPopup" -Value 0 -PropertyType DWord -Force)
    }
    
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_
}

Stop-Transcript
Pop-Location
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

I would create a Win32 app in Intune and deploy the package to test machines. One machine will have "Dell Client Management Service" enabled and running, but won't install Dell Command Update and another machine will just fail upon deployment.

Answer (score 0):

First post, but figured I'd try to help out here.

Unfortunately, I've been back and forth on how I deploy Dell Command | Update, as the dev's with Dell (for lack of terms) suck and are inconsistent.  This time around, I was able to extract the MSI (using the following process [HERE](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000177292/how-to-create-a-dell-command-update-msi-installer-package)) and package it using the IntuneWinAppUtil.  After importing it to Intune, it immediately went out and upgraded my Dell machines in my test tenant.  Here's the settings I used to deploy things:

[IMAGE FROM INTUNE TENANT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQikH.png)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to configue Dell Command Update is to import the ADMX file into Intune and create a configuration profile.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).